# What is meant by ClientOption1 and ClientOption2 in 1222 deadlock graph?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I came across the following in an MSDN Article:

> clientoption1 and clientoption2. Set
>   options on this client connection.
>   This is a bitmask that includes
>   information about options usually
>   controlled by SET statements such as
>   SET NOCOUNT and SET XACTABORT.

Where can I find more information on them? For e.g. in my deadlock graph they have the following values:

```
clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056"
```

What information can I infer from this?

Comment: Don't know. I thought it would likely be the same bitmask format as is used for set_options in the sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes DMV but it [doesn't seem to be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189472%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: They do not appear to be related to [@@Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190763.aspx) either.

Answer (score 4):

This information, while not officially documented, can be queried from the undocumented but well-known `spt_values` table

```sql
-- for clientoptions1
SELECT number,  CONVERT(binary(4), number, 1) AS hex, name,
CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & number = number THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS value
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE type = N'D2'
AND number > 0
ORDER BY number;

-- for clientoptions2
SELECT number, CONVERT(binary(4), number, 1) AS hex, name,
CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & number = number THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS value
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE type = N'SOP'
AND number > 0
ORDER BY number;
```

Each value is a single bit in the field, so you query it using something like this

```sql
CONCAT('SET ANSI_PADDING ', CASE WHEN clientoptions1 & 8192 > 0 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END)
```

[Erik Darling has blogged about this.](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/decoding-client-options-in-sql-server-deadlocks/)